# HTACCESS: How to switch from php/html to php/json version if the request is XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, xmlhttprequest

Please help me:
I have a /php_html/request.php and a /php_json/request.php. If the request is XMLHttpRequest then rewrite the rule so that the result is /php_json/request.php, otherwise the result is /php_html/request.php. The clients just make request only to /php_html/request.php. How do I write rules in htaccess to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, per se. There isn't anything, by default, that distinguishes a request initiated via XMLHttpRequest or otherwise.

So, first you need to do something to distinguish them.

And if you are going to do that, then that thing should be *explicitly asking for JSON*.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Then you can key off that in mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^application/json
```

Comment: I mean, client send request to /php_html/request.php. If the request is XMLHttpRequest, then the request wil redirect to /php_json/request.php. Otherwise (normal request, from browser windows, etc,...), the request will redirect to /php_html/request.php ???

Comment: @HảiVũNguyễn — I understood that. My answer is how you do that.

Comment: I read from this link https://gist.github.com/kemo/2252034 to find out we can get request type in htaccess. But the request to specific php file, i can't. Please help.

Comment: @HảiVũNguyễn — that won't work by default as browsers do not set a `X-Requested-With` header by default. If you're going to set a header then you might as well use a standard one as I recommended.

Comment: https://www.elated.com/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/ has an introductory tutorial for mod_rewrite since you seem to need to get to grips with the absolute basics of the tool.

Comment: I have site https://www.campionre.com/active-exclusive-listings/. If you tick something on the rigth panes to search, a ajax request to the same file/url, but the result is json. Please check it out.